# Undefined variable error in a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried building a batch file using the commands after searching the site. I am trying to find the number/count of a process running, and then use if to execute another command if the number of such processes is more than 5 at any instance.

When I run the statements line by line in the CMD prompt, it works fine.
However, when I run it through a bat file it gives an error saying- a was unexpected at this time.

Here is the script. Also I am not sure if am using the correct If statement (I did search and use before coming to you, but still just incase):

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "iexplore.exe" ') do 
@set var=%a
echo %var%
if %var% <= 5
::echo "hi"
::end if
```

Also, have one more syntax to do so:

```
wmic process where name="iexplore.exe" | find "iexplore.exe" /c
```

but I am not sure how to assign the output of this command to any variable and go on to compare the value of this command to 5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double % for `FOR` command when used in a batch file.

```
@echo off
set var=0
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "explorer.exe" ') do set var=%%a
echo %var%
if %var% leq 5 (
  echo less or equal to 5
) else (
  echo 5 or more
)
```